# Solving system given specific inputs

Tags: equation-solving

I am solving the following system with given inputs for x', q, d, x[0], and y[0]:

```
  ClearAll[x, y, t, q, ode1, ode2, d, sol]
ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; ode2 = 
 x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]
Solve[{ode1, ode2}, {x'[t] = 0, q = .973, d = .1, x[0] = .185, 
  y[0] = 1 - .185}, t, x[t], y[t], y'[t]]
```

Mathematica outputs:

```
    Solve[{Derivative[1][y][t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t], 
  0 == 1 - (3 + 2 d) x[t] - q y[t]}, {0, 0.973, 0.1, 0.185, 0.815}, t,
  x[t], y[t], Derivative[1][y][t]]
```

It does not recognize all of my inputs it seems. I tried replacing the commas with &&s and this did not work either. I thought the syntax for solve was: Solve[eqns, variables]. Am I not conforming to the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had numbers of errors. You also need to use `DSolve` and not `Solve` to solve ode's

```
ClearAll[x, y, t]
q = .973;
d = .1;
ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; 
ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t];
ic = {x[0] == .185, y[0] == 1 - .185};
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

> I want to find values of t and x when x'[t] = 0.

Take the `x[t]` solution obtained, find its derivative, then find where it becomes zero:

```
{solX, solY}= {x[t], y[t]} /. First@DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
solXD = D[solX, t]; (*derivative*)
Plot[solXD, {t, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is a root around `t=0.1`

```
root = t /. FindRoot[solXD, {t, .1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now find what value of  `x` is at this time

```
 solX /. t -> root
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I want to find values of t and x when x'[t] = 0. When I input `ClearAll[x, y, t, x'[t]]
q = .973;
d = .1;
ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; 
ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t];
ic = {x[0] == .185, y[0] == 1 - .185};
DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]` I think this is because I tried to add `x'[t]=0`  to my conditions before. How can I fix this?

Comment: @EverythingEnds  You can not use `x'[t]=0` as initial condition. This is first order ODE. So conditions can be used only for lower derivatives than the order of the ODE which is 1. `I want to find values of t and x when x'[t] = 0` Since now you have the solution `x[t]` then you can take its derivative and find where it is zero.  Do you know how to do this? This becomes just a root finding type problem solve type problem. i.e. Given a function, find where it is zero. The function in this case is `x'[t]` which now you have after solving the ODE system. Do things one step at a time.

Comment: I tried: ``f[t_] := 0.11078566383715296` E^(-8.146` t) (2.9092574018769835` E^(
     3.1459460641365036` t) - 
    3.5192307629305306` E^(5.000053935863496` t) + 
    7.829187531550685`*^-18 E^(6.291892128273006` t) + 
    2.2798645147675938` E^(8.145999999999999` t) + 
    2.505340010096219`*^-16 E^(10.000107871726993` t))
Reduce[Simplify[[f'[t] == 0, t]]]`` and my computer is stuck running

Comment: @EverythingEnds I've added the code now.

Comment: Thanks. Would my method have worked too? How do you recommend learning these sorts of operations? I am finding it difficult to extrapolate from the documentation

Comment: @EverythingEnds I did not understand your method I am afraid. It is best to do things one step at a time and not to try to do too many things in one command. Do one command. Look at the output, make sure it is ok, then do the next step, and so on. In your case, you need to find `x[t]` first, then take its derivative. Then find where derivative is zero. Then use that to find value of `x`. 4 steps, not all in one step which is hard to manage.

Comment: Ok. I saw that there was another root, so I tried: `root2 = t /. FindRoot[solXD, {t, 90}]` and got `36.0651` then tried `solX /. t -> root2` and got `3.04786*10^12` but this is clearly not the case because I have a function `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[sol[t, d, q, x0, 1 - x0], {t, 0, k}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], {{k, 0.01, "time"}, 0.01, 400}, {d,
   0.1, 1}, {q, 0.1, 1}, {x0, 0.01, 1}]` that shows that x is less than 1 at time 36. What is going on here?

Comment: sol is created by `ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d, sol]; ode1 = 
 y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; ode2 = 
 x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]; ic = x[0] + y[0] == 1 

sol[t_, d_, q_, x0_, 
  y0_] = {x[t], 
   y[t]} /. (First@
    Simplify[
     DSolve[{ode1, ode2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]])`

Comment: Please, try to look at the plot of `x[t]`. It blows up after `t=70` or so.  ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WF3go.png)  there is nothing that Mathematica can do about this. So what you get is correct. May be your ODE's are not stable to start with. This is not related to the issue at hand.

Comment: It appears you are correct. So why doesn't Mathematica show Y going to 0 around t = 21? In my ParametricPlot graph, y never reaches 0 until around t = 149. I can make a new thread about this if that is more appopriate

Comment: @EverythingEnds Yes, I think new question on this will be better, as this is now not related to your original question. But it is up to your ofcourse what to do.